Reading more than one csv file is very slow/not at all
I am trying to simply read 2 CSV files from "Spark-The-Definitive-Guide-master" according to their example.
The Kernel never finishes for the following when there is more than 1 CSV file
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("OptimizedLoad") \
    .master("local[8]") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "4g") \
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "4") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "2g") \
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "8") \
    .getOrCreate()

dataPath = "./Spark-The-Definitive-Guide-master/data/retail-data/smallExamp/"
staticDataFrame = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load(dataPath+"*.csv")
staticDataFrame.show()

I have tried a single file successfully.

@mazaneicha thanks for input.  final code works.  import glob files = glob.glob(dataPath+'*.csv') staticDataFrame = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").csv(files) staticDataFrame.show()

That is not what I meant and not how its supposed to be done, but as long as it works...
